# Transition between Subway and Rail in SimCity 4

Tags: simcity-4

I'm new to SimCity 4.  In SimCity 3000, you could build subways and rails and connect the two.  I cannot see the option to do so in SimCity 4.  There is a subway to *elevated* rail connector, but I don't see any connectors for subway to regular rail.  Can subways connect to rails in SimCity 4, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with stock SimCity 4 or Rush Hour, but there is [a popular plop file](http://www.simtropolis.com/forum/files/file/4174-ndex-railtosubway-transition/) which you can add to obtain a building with this functionality.

> #### [NDEX RailtoSubway Transition 2](http://www.simtropolis.com/forum/files/file/4174-ndex-railtosubway-transition/)
>
> A fully-functioning network-enabled plop allows the connection of railroad tracks at the top of the ramp descending down to a connection to the subway network at the bottom is now a possibility!

Answer (score -1):

The author of the NDEX plop says himself it is NOT truly functional.  The elevated cars APPEAR to transition to rail but in fact do not.  They just disappear.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?